# Does an AccessToken also work on Open Data Calls like /search?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, youtube-data-api

So, im working on an Application which compares your youtube channel Data with other similare youtube channels.

Currently im working on the authentication of an user with his youtube account, therefore im Using the OAuth Client.
I already got an code which i can exchange for an `access_token`, which also works.

Sadly, the `access_token` which i get does not work for an simple /search call and gives me an `HTTP 400 -> keyinvalid`

The same call works with an generated ApiKey just fine, but i would prefer to use OAutch.

**My question is, does an accessToken not work with public calls like /search? If it does, what could be my problem here?**

Thanks in Advance!

**EDIT: Added Code Examples**

Step 1: I call the OAuth client with the following url call in an new window with `window.open(url)`

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly&
access_type=offline&
include_granted_scopes=true&
state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
redirect_uri=https://website.com/&
response_type=code&
client_id=9791...7bng.apps.googleusercontent.com"
```

In the Response I extract the Code which looks something like this

```
4/1QCLZnwsntp...sNcE
```

Send this code over an REST API to my Backend which uses this code to exchange it for an `access_token` with an `PHP curl POST call`

```
    $this->connection = curl_init();

    $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token';
    $param = 'code='.$this->credentialsTemp['code'].'&client_id='.$GLOBALS['Youtube-Credentials']['clientId'].'&client_secret='.$GLOBALS['Youtube-Credentials']['clientSecret'].'&redirect_uri=https://website.com/&grant_type=authorization_code';

    curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($this->connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);

    $resp = curl_exec($this->connection);
    curl_close($this->connection);
    $acces_token = json_decode($resp,true)["access_token"];
```

in `$acces_token` should be my access_token which at the Moment looks close to this `ya29.GlyTBtFMdLqKbvgaps...SA2pBORo_Am5UuBuxo8g`

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code. Access token should work when sent to any of the endpoints assuming that it has not expired.

Comment: @DaImTo I just added some more Code, thank you for the fast reply!